# How do I enable middle click on my mouse?

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I just got a new computer recently that has been downgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 7 Professional. I've had this mouse for quite a while. The only information I have on it is that it is wireless, Logitech, and on the bottom it claims "Logitech M310" (I'm not sure if that's important or not). I have already tried to unplug and plug the USB back into the computer. I just don't know how to get it to work.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to middle-click that it isn’t working? Windows itself doesn’t actually make use of middle-clicks by default. Are you trying to middle-click in a browser? Some other software?

Comment: I'm trying to middle click in Chrome. It worked on my last computer perfectly fine, and I'm in Chrome now. I'm not sure how to enable it on this new computer. And I'm also not sure if downgrading my computer from Windows 8 had anything to do with it.

Comment: What part of Chrome? Are you talking about the scrolling function? Can you close a tab by middle-clicking it?

Comment: No, for example, I'm going to someone's Youtube page and on my old computer I could middle click on a video and it would send me to a new tab. I'm trying to do that, but my middle click won't do anything at all. And no I can't close a tab with it either.

Comment: Windows may be using generic (two-button) mouse drivers. Try using the mouse’s [own software](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/wireless-mouse-m310?crid=398&osid=14#section=downloads).

Comment: It's not working. I have tried different commands for my middle mouse button, but none of them work, which is making me believe it might just be the middle mouse itself that's broken.

Comment: Does it still make a clicking noise when you press it? Does the wheel work? Try breathing some hot air from your lungs into it. The humidity could fix a poor electrical connection, and even if it’s just temporary, it will help determine if it’s hardware or software. Also, if you’ve had it for that long, then the metal inside may have built up a bit of a patina which resists the electrical connection. You can try cleaning it, but that’s pretty hard with a mouse button, so tapping it hard usually helps because the pressure causes the little metal pieces to scrape against each other.

Comment: Yeah it's just the mouse itself. I blew hot air, and tapped it like you said, it started working again. I guess I just need a new one.

Comment: Another thing that goes wrong with old devices with mechanical buttons is that they simply wear down. After countless presses, buttons physically wear away a little, but even even a fraction of a millimeter might be enough to prevent the tiny switch from pressing the button. In this case, you can usually open the mouse, locate the little plastic pin that presses on the button, and apply a dab of super-glue to the end. Let it dry, the re-assemble the mouse (do *not* close the mouse until it has dried). Once the super-glue has dried, it causes the pin to be a little longer to press the switch.